# Customer confirmation url leads to a 404 page

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, url, 404

Hello Stack Exchange community,

So we've been running a Magento Multi store for a while now and we haven't run into any trouble yet.

Recently we added another store to our multi store and for some odd reason, customers cannot hit the Confirmation URL as it sends them to a 404 page.

I've already sent a mail to the provider of our template but they told us it's because of the URL Rewrite, which we need for our **SEO**. This is the code we use to generate the URL (which is the default one I assume):

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Deze bevestigingslink</a>
```

Would anyone happen to know why it's linking me to a 404 page?

Comment: Is there no one with this same issue? We cannot figure out why this is happening with our customer confirmation URL..

Comment: This still hasn't been solved yet. I can't find anyone who is able to assist me in this situation. If you don't know the fix for this but you know someone who might, could you please send him/her this topic?